# How to synchronize a CDN folder to a local folder?

Tags: linux, cdn, cloudfiles

Is there a way to synchronize a CDN container (cloudfiles to be more specific) to a local folder? Or is there a way to bulk a download a CDN container?

Comment: You can use the CDN API to write a FUSE file system. If it does not exist already, but I think that it should exists.

Comment: there is a FUSE application that mounts CDN containers, but it can only give access to those files. What i am in need to is an actual synchronized copy of the files

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't seem to be actively maintained, there is [CloudFuse](https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse). It's written in C and has to be compiled on your box (no packages available.

Luckily, there are [articles for setting it up](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mounting-rackspace-cloud-files-to-linux-using-cloudfuse), but here's a rough summary:

#### Installation

```
# Get the packages you need
apt-get install build-essential gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
             libssl-dev libfuse-dev
apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse.git
cd cloudfuse
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

#### Configuration

Create a file named `~/.cloudfuse` (see the main doc to show how to make an automatic mountpoint). Lay the `~/.cloudfuse` file out like so:

```
username=[Account username for authentication, required]
api_key=[API key for authentication with Rackspace]
authurl=https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0 # If LON, use https://lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0
region=[Regional endpoint to use]
use_snet=[True to use Rackspace ServiceNet for connections]
cache_timeout=[Seconds for directory caching, default 600]
```

#### Usage

Now you can mount a directory (new or old) directly

```
$ mkdir /test
$ cloudfuse /test
```

Comment: Thanks, but from what i understood; cloudfuse only mounts the files and it does not keep a local copy of the files, am i correct? if yes then what is the best way to copy them after mounting the folder

Comment: Taking a step back, maybe something like a cron job hooked up with either direct API calls or the use of something like [swiftly](https://github.com/gholt/swiftly) would be much simpler and easier.